# TFIDF for feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, natural-language, tf-idf

Input to tfidf is a list of documents, output is a matrix which contains a numerical value for each (word, document) pair. How can I use that matrix to perform feature selection, i.e. reduce the size of the dictionary?

Comment: One possible option is to use a model with l1 regularization

Answer (score 4):

Normally, [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) is done against some criteria, that is, select all features that best separate/describe your class/target function. That being said, you can select features using their variance or co-variance. In your case, that would mean to only select words (or documents) where the (normalized) TF-IDF score varies the most among documents (or words). In the co-variance case, you'd remove redundant features, that is, remove words that have similar TF-IDF among all documents they occur in (by calculating a correlation coefficient between each word "row" in your TF-IDF matrix), typically keeping the word (document) with the highest frequency, i.e., row (column) sum.

However, rather than feature selection, you might also be interested in [feature extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) if all you want is dimensionality reduction, in particular [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) (sometimes confusingly called "word representations").

Note that I provide more approaches/answers in a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266220/tfidf-for-feature-selection-method-for-unlabeled-text-documents/266394#266394) regarding feature selection of words for *explicitly* **unsupervised** machine learning problems.